# javafx TableView; edit newly added element

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-8

I am trying to auto-start an edit on a newly added element on a TableView. e.g.

```
((TableView)t).getItems().add(new Data(...));
t.edit(t.getItems().size() - 1, tColumn);
```

Although this is giving undefined behavoir for the sepcified cell (for example seeming to be in editing state (visually), while it actually isn't)

From what I understand is that after adding the element, the table itself isn't updated (yet), so adding a runLater call sometimes fixes this problems. Though it isn't consistent.

```
Platform.runLater(() -> t.edit(t.getItems().size() - 1, tColumn));
```

At least this get rid of undefined visual behavior. Its either editing,
 or it isn't (technically and visually).

So I'm searching for a consistent way to trigger the edit after adding the element.

Comment: Any thoughts about this toppic are welcome as well. A thought in another direction is always helpfull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon the solution for this problem... . If you call `TableView#layout()` before you initiate the edit, the cells will be updated correctly giving a fail-proof result.

```
((TableView)t).getItems().add(new Data(...));
t.layout();
t.edit(t.getItems().size() - 1, tColumn);
```

Note that there is no need for a `Platform#runLater()` call.